# jQuery accordion gets minimum height when loaded in collapsed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Some content is collapsed by default with `display: none;`, and I have a JS function that changes its state to display the content. I'd like to load an accordion inside this collapsed content, but when I do, the height of the accordion gets messed up - it gets minimum height, only like 20px or so per tab.

I understand that I probably must have the accordion height reset when the JS function is triggered that expands the content. How can do achieve this? What is the function called? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery accordion height is properly calculated only when its displayed.
Thus, using jQuery UI 1.10.0 and above call

```
$('.myAccordian').accordion("refresh");
```

right after displaying accordion content.

Comment: Word perfectly well, seamless! Though, with the only change that I changed it to #myAccordion, as I'm using an id tag instead of class. Thanks!